# How can I find the word "behind" a cuneiform logogram?

Tags: hittite, sumerian, cuneiform, logograms, akkadian

Suppose I'm looking at a clay tablet, when come across an unfamiliar sign.

[image: a line of cuneiform]

Looking up that second glyph in a sign list, I see that it's called `GAR`; putting that into the ePSD, I'm told it can be read as NINDA "bread". So this word, whatever it is, potentially means "bread".

But now, I'd like to go one step further and find the actual Hittite (or Akkadian) word represented by the logogram. In other words, I'd like to find the word represented by NINDA-an the way *wiyanas* "wine" is represented by GEŠTIN-as or *hassus* "king" is represented by LUGAL-us.

Is there a good way to find this information? For example, is there a database mapping Sumerian logograms to their pronunciations in other languages?

Comment: There's http://psd.museum.upenn.edu/, but it only gives Sumerian and Akkadian readings. (It's a great tool for looking up cuneiform signs in general, though, once you learn to work with the rather dated UI.) Also http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/akkadian lets you search by logogram too, but again is for Akkadian only. Looks like they do have [some resources for Hittite](http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/hittite) too, however.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good list of logograms and their pronunciation and meaning that I have found helpful:
https://github.com/asahala/Cuneiformtools/blob/master/logograms-akkadian/logograms-akkadian.txt